# Динамическое добавление элементов в QListWidget

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

у себя в проекте столкнулся со странным поведением окон в PyQt, необходимо сделать окно с динамически добавляемыми элементами, реализовал это так:

```
class BacklogWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(BacklogWindow, self).__init__()
        # Create QListWidget
        self.myQListWidget = QtGui.QListWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.myQListWidget)
        self.iconfile = join("win32", join("icons", "file.png"))
        self.connect(self, QtCore.SIGNAL("append_to_backlog(PyQt_PyObject, int)"), self.append_to_backlog_ui)

    def test(self):
        window.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL("append_to_backlog(PyQt_PyObject, int)"), unicode("file.txt"), int(0))

    def append_to_backlog_ui(self, name, action):
        print name, action
        myQCustomQWidget = QCustomQWidget()
        print myQCustomQWidget.setTextUp(unicode(name))
        print myQCustomQWidget.setTextDown(unicode(action))
        print myQCustomQWidget.setButtonText(unicode("REVERT"))
        print myQCustomQWidget.button.connect(myQCustomQWidget.button, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.test)

        print myQCustomQWidget.setIcon(self.iconfile)
        # Create QListWidgetItem
        myQListWidgetItem = QtGui.QListWidgetItem(self.myQListWidget)
        # Set size hint
        print myQListWidgetItem.setSizeHint(myQCustomQWidget.sizeHint())
        # Add QListWidgetItem into QListWidget
        print self.myQListWidget.addItem(myQListWidgetItem)
        print self.myQListWidget.setItemWidget(myQListWidgetItem, myQCustomQWidget)

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        app = QtGui.QApplication([])
        window = BacklogWindow()
        window.show()
        window.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL("append_to_backlog(PyQt_PyObject, int)"), unicode("file.txt"), int(0))
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Однако, когда из другого потока создаю сигнал `append_to_backlog(PyQt_PyObject, int)` метод `append_to_backlog_ui(self, name, action)` отрабатывает, но окно по прежнему пусто, никаких элементов не добавляется. Странно то, что когда запускаю этот код, то есть отрабатывает кусок кода под `if __name__ == "__main__"`, то элементы создаются. В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка кроется здесь:

```
def test(self):
    window.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL("append_to_backlog(PyQt_PyObject, int)"), unicode("file.txt"), int(0))
```

Вызывайте метод `emit` для объекта `self`:

```
def test(self):
    self.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL("append_to_backlog(PyQt_PyObject, int)"), unicode("file.txt"), int(0))
```

Кроме того вы вероятно забыли текст в конструктор `QLineWidgetItem` передать:

```
myQListWidgetItem = QtGui.QListWidgetItem(name, self.myQListWidget)
```